# getAccount is Deprecated for MSAL (@azure/msal-angular) and I need to get username after logged in and display it in UI

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

getAccount is Deprecated for MSAL (@azure/msal-angular) and I need to get username after logged in and display it in UI

Comment: Did you figure how to get user details since getAccount is deprectated?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same thing, I found this hacky workaround :

```js
get Username(): string {
    let userInfo: AccountInfo = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];
    return userInfo ? userInfo.username : "";
  }
```

However `getAllAccounts()`, seems to return all locally stored accounts, and its none of its business if their session is active or not.

Luckily [this github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3751#issuecomment-860769723) could clear up ones comprehension about that, plus giving a way to ensure that the stored account has a valid session.